# Unity/Firebase query with startat() works only one time in a lifetime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i hope you can help me.
Currently i make a mobile game for iOS and Android with Unity and i use Firebase Realtime Database to create a global Leaderboard. 
I have the following problem. If i want to make a query from all users, ordered by there  MaxLevel they reached and limited to only users who have reached Level 90+, i get a result only the first time in a lifetime of my app. After the first query i can't make a second query. After closing the game and restart it it works one time again and then stops again.
If i ask without a limitation it works all the time. I found nothing about this Problem in Google, i don't know if i am the first one with this problem since Firebase for Unity is still in the beta phase or am i just to dumb to solve it. 
This is the code i use for the query

//Initi (called in an other script only once)

```
FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl ("https://game-tow.firebaseio.com/");
FirebaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
```

//Query

```
leaderbaordRef = FirebaseRefrence;

public void Query(int level, DatabaseReference leaderboardRef){
  GoldUserList = new List<UserDetails>(); 

  leaderboardRef.Child ("Users").OrderByChild("LevelMax").StartAt(90).GetValueAsync ().ContinueWith (taskGold => {

        if (taskGold.IsFaulted) {
            Debug.LogError (taskGold.Exception);
            return;
        }

        foreach (DataSnapshot GoldUser in taskGold.Result.Children) {
            UserDetails ListUser = new UserDetails (GoldUser.Key);
            GoldUserList.Add (ListUser);
            print ("GoldUser" + ListUser.username);
        }

    });
}
```

Hope someone can help me

Answer (score 0):

I've been having issues with the valuechanged listener on the newest version of the plugin (1.0.1): the event listener is called once when it is attached, but not on any subsequent changes. The data is definitely changing in the database, so I'm assuming this is a bug with the new release (the listeners were being called as expected on version 1.0.0).

Answer (score -1):

Since you call `GetValueAsync()`, the value will indeed be gotten just once. As the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/retrieve-data#read_data_once) says:

> You can use the `GetValueAsync` method to read a static snapshot of the contents at a given path once.

If you'd like to listen for updates, register a listener for the `ValueChanged` event as documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/retrieve-data#listen_for_events):

> You can use the `ValueChanged` event to subscribe on changes of the contents at a given path. This event is triggered once when the listener is attached and again every time the data, including children, changes.
>
> ```
> FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
>   .GetReference("Leaders")
>   .ValueChanged += (object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs args) => {
>     if (args.DatabaseError != null) {
>       Debug.LogError(args.DatabaseError.Message);
>       return;
>     }
>     // Do something with the data in args.Snapshot
>   };
> ```